# Android Listview multiple select

Tags: android, listview

I know there are lots of tutorials and solutions regarding android listview multiple select. But I am getting trouble on finding the correct solution on my kind of implementation. 
I have listview from json object which is shown below. I have a question regarding the implementation of multiple select on following implementation. The following is the class, that extends Asynctask. Now I want to implement multiple select in it. To be straight multiple select to delete multiple items. How could I adopt my code.

I know There are lots of implementation but I am at the end of my project and I have implemented all my list views like following and changing all is now not possible for me.

Thanks in advance

```
 @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {
        user = db.getUserDetails();
        UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();
        JSONObject json = userFunction.getSiteList(user.get("uid"), user.get("uauth"));
        return json;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
        try {
            if(json.has("error_msg")){
                pDialog.dismiss();
                String err = json.getString("error_msg");
                site_error.setText(err);
                site_error.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Dont have any Location", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else{
                pDialog.dismiss();
                // Now since we dont have any error lets put this in the list view.
                site = json.getJSONArray(TAG_SITE);
                for(int i = 0; i < site.length(); i++){
                    JSONObject c = site.getJSONObject(i);
                    //put json obkject on variable
                    String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                    String location = c.getString(TAG_LOCATION);
                 // Adding value HashMap key => value
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    map.put(TAG_ID, id);
                    map.put(TAG_LOCATION, location);
                    sitelist.add(map);
                 // Finding the list view
                    list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.sitelist);
                 // Put data on listview content
                    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(SitePage.this, sitelist,
                            R.layout.site_list,
                            new String[] {TAG_LOCATION,TAG_ID}, new int[] {
                                    R.id.siteLocation});
                    list.setAdapter(adapter);
                 // List View click event
                    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                                int position, long id) {
                            /*Open the new activity for single transaction detail*/
                            Intent intent = new Intent(SitePage.this, AddNewSite.class);
                            intent.putExtra("site", sitelist.get(+position).get("site_location"));
                            intent.putExtra("siteid", sitelist.get(+position).get("site_id"));
                            startActivity(intent);
                           //Toast.makeText(SitePage.this, "You Clicked at "+sitelist.get(+position).get("site_id"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
                }
            }   

        }catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Whatever you want to do with your selected multiple list items you have to implement that logic in your custom adapter.

Comment: I know that , but I am asking how could I ? I dont have separate list adapter class to get the list item rather i have everything on a single class.

Comment: On multiple list items selection just remove those ID's from your list items array list and use adapter.notifyDataSetChanged().